# Enforcing DataTemplate constraints

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

I have default DataTemplates for the different objects in my application.
All my DataTemplates have some sort of "validation" triggers (for example - if a certain boolean field in my object is true, change the font color to red).
This works great!

Now, I would like to allow other developers (in another team, for instance) to create their own DataTemplates which can override my default DataTemplates, BUT I need to make sure they also write those specific validation triggers.
In other words, I would like to enforce some kinds of constraints on their DataTemplates, to make sure they implement these things.
I would rather that these constraints be checked at compile-time and not at runtime, if possible.

Any suggestions on how I can get this done?

Comment: You might be able to do runtime checks, but compile-time and WPF can't go into the same sentence.